# Get aggregation values for all possible distinct entries in group by

Tags: sql

Ok, I know the title is confusing, but the idea is pretty simple.  I just need to figure out how many flights were flown at five different sites during a given time period.  Sometimes a site won't have any flights during the period and this is where I'm having the problem.  If I use:

```
select count(*)
from Flight
where date between '9/9/2013' and '9/15/2013'
group by Site
order by Site
```

I will only get the sites that have actually flown, but I would like to have those sites where there were no flights during during that period (but have flown at other times and have records in the table) still return a value of 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use condition summation.  That is, move the `where` clause to a `case` statement:

```
select sum(case when date between '9/9/2013' and '9/15/2013' then 1 else 0 end)
from Flight
group by Site
order by Site;
```